# Unconventional hybridisation states

Tags: hybridization

I just came across a table with interesting hybridisation schemes I have never seen before. The table is shown below. I was wondering if anyone could give me some examples of atoms in particular molecules which possess one of those weird hybridisation schemes (e.g. spd, p2d2 etc.).

[image]

<sub>Image taken from: Shriver, D.; Weller, M.; Overton, T; Rourke, J.; Armstrong, F. *Inorganic Chemistry*; WH Freeman: New York, 2014</sub>

Comment: Long story very short: These examples do not make any sense, they are a post-rationalisation of geometries and will in most cases not be a good representation of the bonding in such molecules/complexes. Could you please add a citation for the book you are using.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-the-concept-of-hybridization-while-studying-complexes

Comment: Even shorter: find better book.