# What is the electronic structure of Mn in KMnO4 and K2MnO4?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electronic-configuration, hybridization

I know that is is d3s hybrid. But in my book it is unclear which orbitals participate in pi bond with O. I think it should be both p and d orbitals of Mn that do.

Comment: Sigh... please see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-the-concept-of-hybridization-for-transition-metal-complex . Can the hybridisation tag be retired?

Comment: OK, I'll bite.  What is a d3s hybrid?  C'mon man!