# Why are d(xy),d(yz) and d(xz) orbitals involved in d³s hybridisation?

Tags: bond, hybridization, covalent-compounds, valence-bond-theory, crystal-field-theory

Shouldn't d(x²-y²) dxy and dz² orbitals participate? Since this corressponds to the best case overlap?

What factors decide the participating orbitals in hybridisation?

P.S I am well versed with the concepts of CFT and VBT but know little to nothing about other theories lik MOT and Group theory.

Comment: Learn about MOT and group theory.  Hybridization is an inferior concept that should be thrown into the ash heap of history.  Start [here](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch8/mo.html).

Comment: @OscarLanzi so this can't be explained by simple hybrididsation?

Comment: Please, forget hybridisation especially for transition metals, read https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-the-concept-of-hybridization-for-transition-metal-complex . Oh and all atomic d orbitals have the same amount of nett overlap with an s function - zero, as they are eigenfunctions of the same Hermitian operator and are hence orthogonal.

Comment: @user226375 I am not saying it can't be explained bybhybridizatiin.  I am saying it _shouldn't_.  See also the preceding comment.