# Nature of π-bonds in permanganate ion

Tags: bond, orbitals

I was doing a question which asked about the nature of $\pi$ bonds between the $\ce{Mn}$ and $\ce{O}$ atoms in $\ce{MnO4-}$. According to the answer all the three $\pi$ bonds were formed by $p\pi-d\pi$ overlap. However, I know that the hybridisation of $\ce{MnO4-}$ is $d^3s$. Which means three of the $\mathrm{3d}$ orbitals are involved in hybridisation and only two are  left for making $\pi$ bonds. Which means that all the three $\pi$ bonds cannot be formed by  $p\pi-d\pi$ overlap. According to me two of the three $\pi$ bonds are formed by $p\pi-d\pi$ overlap and the third is  formed by $p\pi-p\pi$ overlap using the unhybridised $\mathrm{4p}$ orbital (to which the electron from $\mathrm{4s}$ gets excited from the ground state).

Where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: From what I have learnt on this site, hybridization is a very inadequate and often incorrect concept for describing such compounds.

Comment: [Why is it wrong to use the concept of hybridization for transition metal complexes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-the-concept-of-hybridization-for-transition-metal-complex)

Comment: The primary flaw is assuming that there are three full pi bonds like you might draw in a Lewis structure. In reality, there are pi interactions, but not three bonds worth. The Mn has positive charge and the O's negative, so there is a strong ionic component as well.

Comment: The hybridisation of permanganate is d³s for a duodoctet rule and sp³ for a decaoctet rule. To quote Wikipedia, the academic consensus on this matter is that neither rule is mandatory for  transition metals but the rule has to lie somewhere between, with a seperate rule for each transition metal complex.

Comment: For the people who spam comment how "hybridisation is not appropriate for transition metal complexes"- this is true FOR MO THEORY ONLY and not many people, predictably including the OP,  are that obsessed with, or even familar with, MO theory.