# Do strong field ligands always give d2sp3 hybridisation and weak field ligands give sp3d2 for coordiantion number 6

Tags: coordination-compounds, hybridization, crystal-field-theory

i am actually doing coordination compounds but get confused when it comes to hybridization so wanted to create a short of mine for the exam

Comment: [Why is it wrong to use the concept of hybridization for transition metal complexes?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally true, but weak field ligands, say $NH_3$ or $F^{-}$, can form inner orbital complexes with metals in very high oxidation states ($Co^{3+}$, $Ni^{4+}$ resp. ); $Fe(NH_3)_6$$^{2+}$ is outer orbital but $Co(NH_3)_6$$^{3+}$ is inner orbital, and $CoF_6$$^{3-}$ is outer orbital but $NiF_6$$^{2-}$ is inner orbital.