Why are some hybridization not possible while others are?
I am studying about hybridization and found that hybridization takes place between orbitals with nearly same energy. Also I read that $3s$ and $3p$ can hybridize with $3d$ but $3p$, $3d$ and $4s$ can't even though energy of $4s$ is lower than $3d$. So why can't $3p$, $3d$ and $4s$ intermix? How do we check whether a combination will form or not? Is it completely based on experiments?

In the p-block and d-block, 4s has higher energy. The 3d > 4s is a lie taught by schools. Learn d orbital collapse

@user155568 I read about the topic briefly. I guess I will remember some of those combinations for now.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76726/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-the-concept-of-hybridization-for-transition-metal-complex

While the wording is different, this thing: Why does the 3rd electron shell start filling up with scandium? may answer it best. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You are correct in saying that the orbitals involved in hybridization generally have similar energy for hybridization. However, a phenomenon called d-orbital collapse means that 3d orbitals for s block are higher in energy than the 4s but then for d and p block, the 3d orbitals energy rapidly falls so it becomes lower than the 4s. The 4s is then higher in energy. Some links about d orbital collapse
What is d-orbital collapse?
